# Как достать нужный JSON?

Tags: java, json

Итак, на вход я получаю вот такой массив из JSON-объектов. Вопрос такой: как достать нужный мне по индексу объект с помощью `Java`? Эти данные я получаю в виде строки `String`.

```
[
  {
    "name": "London",
    "local_names": {
      "af": "Londen",
      "ar": "لندن",
      "ascii": "London",
      "az": "London",
      "bg": "Лондон",
      "ca": "Londres",
      "da": "London",
      "de": "London",
      "el": "Λονδίνο",
      "en": "London",
      "eu": "Londres",
      "fa": "لندن",
      "feature_name": "London",
      "fi": "Lontoo",
      "fr": "Londres",
      "gl": "Londres",
      "he": "לונדון",
      "hi": "लंदन",
      "hr": "London",
      "hu": "London",
      "id": "London",
      "it": "Londra",
      "ja": "ロンドン",
      "la": "Londinium",
      "lt": "Londonas",
      "mk": "Лондон",
      "nl": "Londen",
      "no": "London",
      "pl": "Londyn",
      "pt": "Londres",
      "ro": "Londra",
      "ru": "Лондон",
      "sk": "Londýn",
      "sl": "London",
      "sr": "Лондон",
      "th": "ลอนดอน",
      "tr": "Londra",
      "vi": "Luân Đôn",
      "zu": "ILondon"
    },
    "lat": 51.5085,
    "lon": -0.1257,
    "country": "GB"
  },
  {
    "name": "London",
    "local_names": {
      "ar": "لندن",
      "ascii": "London",
      "bg": "Лондон",
      "de": "London",
      "en": "London",
      "fa": "لندن، انتاریو",
      "feature_name": "London",
      "fi": "London",
      "fr": "London",
      "he": "לונדון",
      "ja": "ロンドン",
      "lt": "Londonas",
      "nl": "London",
      "pl": "London",
      "pt": "London",
      "ru": "Лондон",
      "sr": "Лондон"
    },
    "lat": 42.9834,
    "lon": -81.233,
    "country": "CA"
  },
  {
    "name": "London",
    "local_names": {
      "ar": "لندن",
      "ascii": "London",
      "en": "London",
      "fa": "لندن، اوهایو",
      "feature_name": "London",
      "sr": "Ландон"
    },
    "lat": 39.8865,
    "lon": -83.4483,
    "country": "US",
    "state": "OH"
  },
  {
    "name": "London",
    "local_names": {
      "ar": "لندن",
      "ascii": "London",
      "en": "London",
      "fa": "لندن، کنتاکی",
      "feature_name": "London",
      "sr": "Ландон"
    },
    "lat": 37.129,
    "lon": -84.0833,
    "country": "US",
    "state": "KY"
  },
  {
    "name": "London",
    "local_names": {
      "ascii": "London",
      "ca": "Londres",
      "en": "London",
      "feature_name": "London"
    },
    "lat": 36.4761,
    "lon": -119.4432,
    "country": "US",
    "state": "CA"
  }
]
```

Comment: *"массив из JSON-объектов"* - это один json документ, элементов верхнего уровня которого является массив

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для работы с JSON использую `org.json`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20220320</version>
</dependency>
```

**Код с подробными пояснениями**

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JSONProcessing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // строка содержит упомянутый в вопросе Json
        String jsonBody = "/** на этом месте должно быть содержание вашего json'а */";
        // т.к. корень нашего документа - это массив, 
        // то на основе имеющейся строки создаем объект JSONArray
        // если бы документ начинался и заканчивался { ... }, 
        // то нужно было бы создать JSONObject
        JSONArray root = new JSONArray(jsonBody);
        // в переменной содержится индекс. 
        // при необходимости можно будет его вывести в параметры метода
        int index = 0; 
        // из корневого массива по индексу получаем JSONObject
        // назвал его cityJson
        JSONObject cityJson = root.getJSONObject(index);
        // по ключу name, получаем соответствующее поле
        // обратите внимание на то, что я пользуюсь методом getString
        // им можно получать только строки, 
        // если вы попытаетесь получить с помощью данного метода числа, массивы или другие объекты, 
        // то получите ошибку... 
        // для этих целей есть другие методы
        String name = cityJson.getString("name");
        // по ключу local_names получаем объект, содержащий локализованные названия города
        // его я получаю с помощью метода getJSONObject
        // именно об этом я говорил выше
        // в качестве результата получаем объект типа JSONObject
        JSONObject localNames = cityJson.getJSONObject("local_names");
        // из него по ключу можем получить какое-то поле... 
        // например, содержащее французкое(наверное) название
        String french = localNames.getString("fr");
        // по ключу lat с помощью метода getFloat получаем широту
        Float latitude = cityJson.getFloat("lat");
        // аналогично с долготой
        Float longitude = cityJson.getFloat("lon");
        // как получать строки уже было и со страной должны сами разобраться
        String country = cityJson.getString("country");
        
        // форматируем все это дело для вывода
        String out = String.format(
                "name: %s\nfrench: %s\nlatitude: %f\nlongitude: %f\ncountry: %s", 
                name, french, latitude, longitude, country
        );
        // выводим
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```

**Вывод**

```
name: London
french: Londres
latitude: 51,508499
longitude: -0,125700
country: GB
```