# Как спарсить Джексоном массив без имени

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, resttemplate

Пытаюсь получить ответ от погодной апишки
апишка на запрос координат города присылает такой ответ

```
[
    {
        "name": "Moscow",
        "local_names": {
            "it": "Mosca",
            "zh": "莫斯科",
            "lv": "Maskava",
            "id": "Moskwa",
            "ay": "Mosku",
            "lt": "Maskva",
            "ascii": "Moscow",
            "sh": "Moskva",
            "uz": "Moskva",
            "st": "Moscow",
            "co": "Moscù",
            "bo": "མོ་སི་ཁོ།",
            "fi": "Moskova",
            "wo": "Mosku",
            "dz": "མོསི་ཀོ",
            "sl": "Moskva",
            "ps": "مسکو",
            "sc": "Mosca",
            "hr": "Moskva",
            "kv": "Мӧскуа",
            "tk": "Moskwa",
            "sr": "Москва",
            "mg": "Moskva",
            "ko": "모스크바",
            "wa": "Moscou",
            "sg": "Moscow",
            "sv": "Moskva",
            "ch": "Moscow",
            "mn": "Москва",
            "ta": "மாஸ்கோ",
            "am": "ሞስኮ",
            "an": "Moscú",
            "io": "Moskva",
            "su": "Moskwa",
            "ro": "Moscova",
            "oc": "Moscòu",
            "feature_name": "Moscow",
            "bg": "Москва",
            "nn": "Moskva",
            "en": "Moscow",
            "li": "Moskou",
            "ga": "Moscó",
            "ak": "Moscow",
            "ba": "Мәскәү",
            "da": "Moskva",
            "so": "Moskow",
            "ru": "Москва",
            "be": "Масква",
            "is": "Moskva",
            "eo": "Moskvo",
            "cu": "Москъва",
            "uk": "Москва",
            "cs": "Moskva",
            "sk": "Moskva",
            "vo": "Moskva",
            "ab": "Москва",
            "qu": "Moskwa",
            "kg": "Moskva",
            "cy": "Moscfa",
            "az": "Moskva",
            "pl": "Moskwa",
            "jv": "Moskwa",
            "fo": "Moskva",
            "ia": "Moscova",
            "lg": "Moosko",
            "hu": "Moszkva",
            "vi": "Mát-xcơ-va",
            "eu": "Mosku",
            "mt": "Moska",
            "nb": "Moskva",
            "pt": "Moscou",
            "tl": "Moscow",
            "ar": "موسكو",
            "he": "מוסקווה",
            "gv": "Moscow",
            "sw": "Moscow",
            "de": "Moskau",
            "gd": "Moscobha",
            "ja": "モスクワ",
            "yo": "Mọsko",
            "dv": "މޮސްކޯ",
            "cv": "Мускав",
            "bi": "Moskow",
            "fa": "مسکو",
            "gn": "Mosku",
            "no": "Moskva",
            "iu": "ᒨᔅᑯ",
            "na": "Moscow",
            "bs": "Moskva",
            "kk": "Мәскеу",
            "ml": "മോസ്കോ",
            "zu": "IMoskwa",
            "za": "Moscow",
            "ca": "Moscou",
            "hi": "मास्को",
            "ln": "Moskú",
            "la": "Moscua",
            "mi": "Mohikau",
            "av": "Москва",
            "gl": "Moscova - Москва",
            "es": "Moscú",
            "os": "Мæскуы",
            "af": "Moskou",
            "se": "Moskva",
            "ht": "Moskou",
            "nl": "Moskou",
            "kn": "ಮಾಸ್ಕೋ",
            "yi": "מאסקווע",
            "ty": "Moscou",
            "br": "Moskov",
            "el": "Μόσχα",
            "ce": "Москох",
            "tt": "Мәскәү",
            "tr": "Moskova",
            "ku": "Moskow",
            "te": "మాస్కో",
            "ie": "Moskwa",
            "sq": "Moska",
            "et": "Moskva",
            "ss": "Moscow",
            "hy": "Մոսկվա",
            "tg": "Маскав",
            "kl": "Moskva",
            "kw": "Moskva",
            "mr": "मॉस्को",
            "ka": "მოსკოვი",
            "ky": "Москва",
            "fr": "Moscou",
            "my": "မော်စကိုမြို့",
            "sm": "Moscow",
            "fy": "Moskou",
            "mk": "Москва",
            "ms": "Moscow",
            "th": "มอสโก",
            "ug": "Moskwa",
            "ur": "ماسکو",
            "bn": "মস্কো"
        },
        "lat": 55.7504461,
        "lon": 37.6174943,
        "country": "RU",
        "state": "Moscow"
    }
]
```

но в ответ получаю такой эксепшен

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.romanperkov.spring.rest.entity.cord] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.romanperkov.spring.rest.entity.cord` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.romanperkov.spring.rest.entity.cord` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:315)
    at com.romanperkov.spring.rest.Communication.test(Communication.java:81)
    at com.romanperkov.spring.rest.App.main(App.java:35)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.romanperkov.spring.rest.entity.cord` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.romanperkov.spring.rest.entity.cord` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:284)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:242)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:105)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.romanperkov.spring.rest.entity.cord` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1468)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1242)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:604)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3521)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:273)
    ... 7 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Я так понял, что проблема в том что ответ апишки начинается с квадратных скобок , то есть она возвращает массив, но он без имени , как в таких случаях действовать?

класс описывающий сущность которую надо получить из апи респонса

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class cord {

    private List<String> name;
}
```

Решение проблемы заключается в том что бы указать класс как массив

```
String url="http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=QWERTY&limit=5&appid=fe7e6bcec3fedc63d4a158abd1c3c3eb";
        cord[] responseEntity=restTemplate.getForObject
                (url.replace("QWERTY","москва"), cord[].class);
        System.out.println(responseEntity[0]);
```

Comment: @МихаилРебров ответ с такого запроса  http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=москва&appid=fe7e6bcec3fedc63d4a158abd1c3c3eb

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436092/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-json/1436110#1436110

Comment: как время будет посмотрю что там с Jackson'ом

Comment: нет, я хочу бота научить прогноз погоды делать, но апишка запросы на прогноз принимает только с координатами, соответственно я сейчас пишу сервис который бы для сервиса прогноза делал бы запрос на эту апишку и с ответа бы получал координаты которые бот мог бы использовать для того, что бы сделать прогнозирующий запрос.

Comment: посмотрю сейчас

Comment: @МихаилРебров Ваша ссылка позволила мне найти решение проблемы       String url="http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=QWERTY&limit=5&appid=2ca5fe61073486881897b1dd4ac6d004";
        cord[] responseEntity=restTemplate.getForObject
                (url.replace("QWERTY","москва"), cord[].class);
        System.out.println(responseEntity[0]);

Comment: тоесть когда указываем класс надо дописать что это массив []

Comment: Либо, как вариант, использовать [JsonNode](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-to-jsonnode#jsonnode), т.е. использовать [JsonNode.get(int index)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get(int))...

Comment: `@МихаилРебров Ваша ссылка позволила мне найти решение проблемы`...я к сожалению прочитал это уже после того как решил)))

Comment: @Roman добавил UPDATE в конце с рабочим RestTemplate

Comment: если возникнут проблемы с restTemplate - пишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Модель

Описываем объект, который мы хотим извлечь

Локализованные названия городов проще вытащить в `Map<String, String>`

```
private Map<String, String> localNames;
```

Для того, чтобы не идти против конвенций и называть переменные CamelCase'ом как положено, а не snake_case'ом как в JSON'e поставим аннотацию над полем с именем поля в JSON'е

```
@JsonProperty("local_names")
private Map<String, String> localNames;
```

Чтобы было удобнее работать с локализованными именами, лежащими в Map можно добавить вспомогательный метод извлекающий нужное имя по коду локали

```
public String getLocalName(String locale){
    return localNames.get(locale);
}
```

Соответственно, чтобы получить французкое название понадобится вызвать:

```
city.getLocalName("fr")
```

Класс полностью:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class City {
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("local_names")
    private Map<String, String> localNames;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lon;
    private String country;
    private String state;

    public City() {
        this.localNames = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getLocalNames() {
        return localNames;
    }

    public void setLocalNames(Map<String, String> localNames) {
        this.localNames = localNames;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getLocalName(String locale){
        return localNames.get(locale);
    }
}
```

#### Извлечение

Самый неприятный момент в извлечении объектов из JSON'а - это параметризируемые типы(они же дженерики)

В нашем случае нам в лоб возвращается список объектов и мы должны как-то определить тип.

Указать `List.class` мы не можем.

Для таких задач в Jackson есть фабрика типов, которая поможет создать описание типа дженерика на основе класса коллекции и класса вложенного объекта

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, City.class);
```

Собственно код, извлекающий объекты из json'а

```
String json = getSOJsonString(); // получаем JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// Так как дженерики нельзя просто указать через `getClass` 
// Создаем тип для извлечения коллекции объектов 
// с помощью встроенных в Jackson конструкторов типов
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, City.class);
// маппим одно на другое
List<City> cities = mapper.readValue(json, type);
for (City city: cities) {
    // System.out.println(city.getName());
    // тут выводим все что нам надо
}
```

Все извлекается корректно.
Вот пример извлечения из дебаггера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### UPDATE

На момент начала написания ответа кода с RestTemplate в вопросе не было, поэтому дополняю вариант с онным.

Конкретно в случае с `RestTemplate` тип лучше указывать с помощью вспомогательного класса Spring'а, предназначенного ровно для того же что и вышеописанная фабрика.

В Spring есть класс `ParameterizedTypeReference` с помощью которого можно описать тип параметризируемого объекта (или дженерика)

Делается это так:

```
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<City>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<City>>() {};
```

при этом данный тип можно пристроить далеко не в каждый метод RestTemplate.

Лучше всего воспользоваться следующим способом:

```
restTemplate.exchange(myUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, type);
```

В итоге код получения и извлечения объектов из REST'сервиса будет выглядеть так:

```
String url="http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=QWERTY&limit=5&appid=fe7e6bcec3fedc63d4a158abd1c3c3eb";
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<City>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<City>>() {};
List<City> cities = restTemplate.exchange(url.replace("QWERTY","москва"), HttpMethod.GET, null, type).getBody();

for (City city: cities) {
    System.out.println(city);
}
```

**Замечание:**
В вашем случае будет только не класс `City`, а класс `coord`
У меня не поднялась рука так называть класс, поэтому я взял название из упомянутого мной аналогичного ответа.
Классы надо именовать с большой буквы.
Это конвенция.

Как-то так, наверное...

```
String url="http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=QWERTY&limit=5&appid=fe7e6bcec3fedc63d4a158abd1c3c3eb";
ParameterizedTypeReference<List<coord>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<coord>>() {};
List<coord> coords = restTemplate.exchange(url.replace("QWERTY","москва"), HttpMethod.GET, null, type).getBody();

for (coord c: coords) {
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: а как вы получаете json в виде стринга ? это уже не RestTemplate надо использовать?

Comment: я ваш JSON к себе просто сохранил и извлекаю его потом. для вас все будет тоже самое.  главное правильно описать объект и указать тип (можете мой пример использовать). А под копотом restTemplate будет все тоже самое происходить

Comment: @Roman могу добавить блок с restTemplate в ответ

Comment: если можно А то мой пока выглядит так cord responseEntity=restTemplate.getForObject
                (url, cord.class);

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите распарсить объект, а вам приходит список. Передайте `TypeReference` c типом `List<City>`, чтобы распарсить список:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String content = "[{\"name\": \"Moscow\"}]";
TypeReference<List<City>> type = new TypeReference<>() {};
List<City> cities = objectMapper.readValue(content, type);
System.out.println(cities);
```